# Micropython: Unable to fix IndexError: bytes index out of range issue

Tags: python, mqtt, microcontroller, esp32, micropython

I am trying to connect ESP32 based MQTT client *umqtt.simple.py* with Micropython code to a MQTT broker. But its throwing **IndexError: bytes index out of range issue**. error every time, when start to execute the program. I have been tried and reviewed each and every posts here and there to fix this issue,, but didn't get any success to fix this **IndexError: bytes index out of range issue** at all and very frustrating how to fix this? Any help here on this to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanking you.

Here is the code:

```
from time import sleep
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient
from machine import Pin
from dht import DHT22
SERVER ='my.cloudmqtt.com'
CLIENT_ID='ESP32_TH'
PORT=1883
TOPIC=b'temp_humidity'
client=MQTTClient(CLIENT_ID,SERVER,PORT,"cloudmqttusername","cloudmqqttpassword")
client.connect()
sensor=DHT22(Pin(13,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP))
while True:
     try:
          sensor.measure()
          t = sensor.temperature()
          h = sensor.humidity()
          if isinstance(t, float) and isinstance(h, float):
               msg = (b'{0:3.1f},{1:3.1f}'.format(t,h))
               client.publish(TOPIC,msg)
               print(msg)
          else:
               print('invalid sensor value')
     except OSError:
          print ('failed to read sensor')
     sleep(4)
```

And Here an error:

```
>>> client.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "umqttsimple.py", line 102, in connect
IndexError: bytes index out of range
>>>
```

[Please check the screenshot here for error line 102 in IDE coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH2az.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to ask reproducible questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing any code but please try: ``msg = b'Hello #%d'`` . Check that you have a ``b`` before your message.

Comment: checkout how I did it here https://github.com/programandoconro/Programming-Locker/blob/master/IoT/MicroPython/mqtt/mqtt.py

Comment: Please check for the code i'm using. Thanks.

Comment: from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient
                                                                               
SERVER ='my.cloudmqtt.com'
                                                       
CLIENT_ID='ESP32_TH'
                                                                        PORT=1883
                                                    TOPIC=b'temp_humidity'
 client=MQTTClient(CLIENT_ID,SERVER,PORT,"cloudmqttusername","cloudmqqttpassword")
                                                                   client.connect()

Comment: please add the code to the question, there is an edit button below it.

Comment: Error Msg:                                                                             
                                                                                              
>>> client.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "umqttsimple.py", line 102, in connect
IndexError: bytes index out of range

Comment: use ``b`` before every string related to the mqtt(client,server,topic,message) view this: https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/issues/110

Comment: Code and error message has been added to the question. Please review again to keep helping to fix this issue on this. Thanks.

Comment: Just used 'b' before every string related to the mqtt(client,server,topic,message). Got the same error.

Comment: Try the simplest example first (without using the sensor data), just try to publish a hello-world to see if the error remains.

Comment: I think issue is not with the sensor, but with the micropython-umqttsimple' publish code. It tries to connect to the broker but it throwing back an index error. I have added the code and error message to the question. Please review again to keep helping to fix this issue on this.

Comment: Please try to publish data to a public broker like ``broker.emqx.io`` to check if the problem is in the broker or the client. https://www.emqx.io/mqtt/public-mqtt5-broker

Comment: I tried to connect with `broker.emqx.io` public broker and it didn't throw any error, but with my used MQTT broker its throwing `IndexError: bytes index out of range` type error. I think its trying to connect to the used MQTT broker, but code from  `umqtt.simple.py`  MQTTClient not executing as per its parameter settings within the code and don't know how to change these parameters to keep byte within the index range.

Comment: So I think it means the problem is in your broker. Try to reinstall it from source.

Comment: okay! let me check on this. Thanks.

Comment: @kpin404  were you able to fix this issue?  if so, could you post your solution as an answer here.

Comment: I wonder if you're hitting a variant of [this issue](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/issues/445)? What happens if set an explicit keepalive on the client (`client=MQTTClient(CLIENT_ID,SERVER,PORT,"someuser","some.secret", keepalive=30)`)?